# ¿Cómo comparar elementos de diferentes objetos(arreglos) POO?

Tags: java, poo, lista, objeto

Mediante objetos, estoy tratando de hacer un programa que compare elementos y si estos son iguales arrojarlos a una lista nueva y si un elemento no esta en mi objeto A PERO lo esta en mi Objeto B entonces se pasa como negativo(-) y de caso contrario sería positivo (+)

Es decir...

```
 // Lista A   Lista B
   A         A
   2         2
   C         C
   20.2      20.2
   G         E
   H         F
   I         G
   L         J
   M         K
   N         N
             O
             P 


Lista C = A 2 C 20.2 -G +E +F G -H -I +J -L -M N -O -P
```

Mi clase esta basada en:

```
public class ConceptosLista {
    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private double monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;
    private String concepto;
    private double montoConvenio;


    public ConceptosLista(String posicion, String numeroParte, String descripcion, double monto, String cambioPrecio,
            String concepto, double montoConvenio) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numeroParte = numeroParte;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.cambioPrecio = cambioPrecio;
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.montoConvenio = montoConvenio;
    }


}
```

Que son los datos que voy a comparar.

Y en mi clase Main, cree dos objetos con sus respectivos datos:

```
List<ConceptosLista> lstA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ConceptosLista> lstB = new ArrayList<>();


        ConceptosLista objPintura = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 407.25, "0", "HYP", 0);
        lstA.add(objPintura);

        ConceptosLista objPintura2 = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 300.20, "0", "HYP", 0);
        lstB.add(objPintura);

        List<ConceptosLista> lstC = new ArrayList<>();
```

E hice una clase aparte para poder crear las funciones de checar si son iguales o no y generar la lista:

```
public class GenerarLista {

    ArrayList<ConceptosLista> ListaConceptos = new ArrayList<>();

    public  void agregarConceptos(ConceptosLista objConceptos){
        ListaConceptos.add(objConceptos);
    }
       public String Listar(){




            return null;
        }

}
```

Había creado un programa que me comparaba pero no estaba basado en POO si no fue un algoritmo sencillo el cual tengo que implementar en POO, y es el siguiente:

```
//Primer for compara los valores de la lista A CON LA LISTA B
     for (String valorA : a){
         //Si son iguales los agrega directo a mi nueva lista C
         if(!valorA.equals(" ")){
             if(b.contains(valorA)){
                 c.add(valorA);
                 //Si no, los agrega pero con "-"
             }else{
                 c.add("-"+valorA);
             }
         }
     }

//Aplicar cada funcion para cada elemento de la lista

     for (String valorB : b){
         if(!valorB.equals(" ")){
             if(!a.contains(valorB)){
                 c.add("+"+valorB);
             }
         }
     }

//Este for manda imprimir la lista C
     for (String valorC : c){
         System.out.print(valorC+" ");
     }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a aplicar en POO, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

que tal espero te encuentres bien.

Si tu código esta exactamente de esta manera una de las razones por la cual no puedo haberte funcionado es que estas agregando el mismo objeto a dos agregas distintos, prueba con eso donde dice `lstB.add(objPintura)` debería ser  `lstB.add(objPintura2)`, de esta manera.

```
List<ConceptosLista> lstA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ConceptosLista> lstB = new ArrayList<>();


    ConceptosLista objPintura = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 407.25, "0", "HYP", 0);
    lstA.add(objPintura);

    ConceptosLista objPintura2 = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 300.20, "0", "HYP", 0);
    lstB.add(objPintura2);

    List<ConceptosLista> lstC = new ArrayList<>();
```

Segunda revisión, dentro de tu for each en ves de `String valueA: a` este debería de ser `String valueA: lstA`, de la siguiente manera.

```
//Primer for compara los valores de la lista A CON LA LISTA B
 for (String valorA : lstA){
     //Si son iguales los agrega directo a mi nueva lista C
     if(!valorA.equals(" ")){
         if(b.contains(valorA)){
             c.add(valorA);
             //Si no, los agrega pero con "-"
         }else{
             c.add("-"+valorA);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!
Duda... al momento de colocar: lstA.add(objPintura); lo que estoy haciendo es que toodos los datos del objeto ya se guardaron en una sola lista? en este caso "lstA"?, o sea, no requiero crear un for each para cada elemento, nos es así?